# How do I exit a while loop by pressing enter?

Tags: java, input, enter

I am trying to get a while loop to break by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on a keyboard. My code is:

```
package javaapplication4;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Double> numbers = new ArrayList( );
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the numbers seperated by a space: ");
            numbers.add(keyboard.nextDouble());
           //want the while loop to break here by pressing "enter" after entering array values
        }
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a loop for getting the input, or `nextDouble`. What you really want is one line of input, which you then split into a list of doubles. So use `nextLine`, split it, and parse each item. Something like this:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Double> numbers = new ArrayList( );
String input = keyboard.nextLine();
for(String item : input.split(" ")){
    numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(item));
}
```

This ignores any sort of input validation, but it shows a general approach.

This will work because once you hit "enter", it ends the first line, meaning the scanner can move past the `nextLine` into the bulk of your code. Since you never try to read anything more, it doesn't block waiting for any more input, and can successfully exit once done.

Comment: *Just a note*: `Double.parseDouble(input)` will try to parse the empty line, which obviously fails. **Edit**: your edit won't fix that :P

Comment: @Tom I'm not seeing it try to parse the empty line. For an input of `1 2 3 4 5` on my machine the output is `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]`.

Comment: Try it with an empty line :). I know that you said, that you omitted the checks and that's why my commend is meant to be a "note", not a critique.

Answer (score 1):

I myself like to use try { ... } catch (NumberFormatException) so when you get a blank line (ie enter) your catch block is activated and you've escaped the loop

```
try {
    while (true) {
      System.out.println("Please enter the numbers seperated by a space: ");
      numbers.add(keyboard.nextDouble());
      //want the while loop to break here by pressing "enter" after entering array values
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {}
System.out.println(numbers);
```

Comment: This seems to just keep waiting for you to enter a double regardless of how many times you press enter. It simply ignores the newlines. (Also, I think it should be `InputMismatchException`, not `NumberFormatException`).

Comment: @resueman *"This seems to just keep waiting for you to enter a double regardless of how many times you press enter."* because `keyboard.nextDouble()` won't even bother starting to read until a token was entered. And "return" is not a valid token (with Scanners default delimiter).

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class JavaApplication4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Double> numbers = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println("Please enter the numbers seperated by a space: ");

        String line = keyboard.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
        while(token.hasMoreTokens()) {
            numbers.add(Double.parseDouble(token.nextToken()));
        }

        System.out.println("Numbers: " + numbers);

    }
```

}

Comment: Even though `StringTokenizer` still works it is already outdated and should be replaced by `String#spit`. Even the JavaDoc of this class recommends that.

Comment: Tom, you are correct, String#split is the better approach. I guess I am showing my age. :-(